# Creating a grid from pixels of a georaster in Python with GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas, rasterio, vector-grid

Let say we have a georaster file with a given resolution. Is is possible to create a grid where each cell of the grid correspond to each pixel? Is it possible to store this grid as a GeoPandas dataframe?

This is a example of the image that I have.

```
fname = 'myFile.tif'
f = rasterio.open(fname)
show(f)
```

[image]

This is what I tried to do but I am not able to convert the meshgrid as a geopandas dataframe.

```
from affine import Affine
import xarray as xr
da = xr.open_rasterio(fname)
transform = Affine.from_gdal(*da.attrs['transform'])
nx, ny = da.sizes['x'], da.sizes['y']
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(nx)+0.5, np.arange(ny)+0.5) * transform
```

The goal is to have a GeoPandas dataframe in which each rows correspond to a pixel with the value of the georaster because I want to make spatial join with other GeoPandas dataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem as following:

```
def geopandasFromRaster(geofile):
    mask = None
    with rasterio.Env():
        with rasterio.open(geofile) as src:
            image = src.read(1) # first band
            results = (
            {'properties': {'raster_val': v}, 'geometry': s}
            for i, (s, v) 
            in enumerate(
                shapes(image, mask=mask, transform=src.transform)))
    geoms = list(results)
    return gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(geoms)


gdf = geopandasFromRaster(fname)
```